# How to stream an Mp3 file using Socket programming in Java JMF

Tags: java, sockets, stream, mp3, jmf

I am doing a project in Java
I am trying to stream an Mp3 file to client from server Using Socket programming
and Play it on client machine using JMF
But I am help less in that

Is this thing possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be streaming I would use RED5 ( java based streaming server) coupled with its rtmp client library.